# NLog try another target when main target failed to log

Tags: nlog

I'm using NLog in my project, and one of the requirement is that if the log to a given file fails (for whatever reason), I must write the log in the event viewer.

How can I achieve that in the configuration file of NLog ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it.
The key is to use `FallbackGroup` as type of a target, and place the targets in correct order inside.

Example:

```
<target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="f" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
  <target xsi:type="File"
        name="f"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/${processname}-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />

  <target xsi:type="EventLog"
          name="eventLog"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"
          source="MySource"
          log="Application" />
</target>
```

This has solved my problem.